# Visual Studio 2008 remains front most window debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2008, monitor, multiple-monitors

I suspect this could be posted elsewhere but it seems to only be an issue with VS 2008 - I haven't experienced this before and it is frustrating me.  I run VS 2008 on my dev box (Win 7 Ultimate, core i7 processor, 9GB RAM) and noticed that recently when I run a particular app I'm developing out of the debugger, VS then becomes the frontmost window (like how the Task Manager window remains on top) and until I shut down VS, it'll forever want to be the frontmost window.

I've got dual monitors on this box for what that's worth.

It doesn't have any add-ons (resharper, etc.) installed.

Worst of all, while it is repeatable, it doesn't happen the first time every time, but it will eventually happen that it suddenly won't let anyone else pop to the front.  Usually after maybe 5 runs.

I don't see this behavior with any other apps on the box ever.

Ideas?

---

Additional info:  Seems to only happen when I'm running one particular CPU and disk-intensive app through the debugger.

Comment: Is this behavior limited to a single project or can you repro with multiple projects?

Comment: Running some tests with another one now.  Not sure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to be solved.  Oddly enough, I was running through a checklist of optimizations to VS 2008 and when I did the one that involved opening IE and changing the Tools->Options->Internet Options,  under Advanced tab I unchecked the "Check for publisher's certificate revocation" in the Security section.

Now I can't make this happen anymore - and the lag that I would see when exiting a program running out of the debugger is gone.  Happy Days.